flutter: Module 'path_provider_foundation' not found
Hello I am trying to run my flutter project, but I am getting the following error:
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'path_provider_foundation' not found
/Users/juliapak/Desktop/app_projects/testerapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

What I have tried so far:
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get

Then I opened Runner.xcodeproj and tried running from there. I also tried running from Runner.xcworkspace

Ok I solved it for now..
Had to go into Runner.xcworkspace and add arm64 to the excluded architectures for simulator
Looks like this:


For me the problem was solved by changing the Xcode Run Scheme from Release to Debug.


I delete the ios files and recreated again and solved my issue
deleting ios files;
rm -rf ios

For recreating;
flutter create .

